# Order of magnitude in integration

Tags: calculus

Let $0<a<b<1$. Let $g(x)$ be a strictly increasing function on $(a,b)$ such that $g(a)=0$. I know that 
$$\int_a^bxg(x)dx>b^2.$$
Does there exist a constant $C>0$ such that 
$$\int_a^b (x-a)\cdot g(x)dx>Cb^2.$$

In other words, does there exist a positive constant $C'\in(0,1)$ such that $\int_a^ba\cdot g(x)<C'b^2.$

It's clear to me that if I replace the $x$ in the original integral by the lowest value it can take over the interval of intergration, the result can only decrease, as $g$ is strictly increasing and $a>0$. The issue is that $a$ can be arbitrarily close to $b$ and then both $\int_a^bxg(x)dx$ and $\int_a^ba\cdot g(x)$ go to zero, so I can't tell if the order is preserved. The fact that the bounds are given in terms up the upper limit of integration doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Is that first inequality some given property of $g$ or is it claimed to be a property holding for all strictly increasing $g$ vanishing at zero? Because it is definitely not universal, take $g(x)=\epsilon(x-a)$ for small $\epsilon$...

Comment: Anyway, because of linearity the fact that the bound involves $b$ is irrelevant, just replace $g$ by $g/b^2$ and then the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is *Yes*. Here is a sketch why.

Relax the conditions on $g$ to allow it to be increasing (as opposed to strictly increasing), with $g(a)=0$; let $\mathcal G$ be the set of all such $g.$ Let $\Gamma\subset\mathbb R^2$ be the set of all points of form $\left(\int_a^b g_u(x)dx,\,\int_a^b x g_u(x)dx\right)$, for all $u\in[0,b-a]$ where $g_u = \chi_{[b-u,b]}$ is  the indicator function of $[b-u,b]$. $\Gamma$ is a segment of the graph of the quadratic polynomial $ub-u^2/2$.  Let $F$ be the closed convex  cone generated by $\Gamma$. If $(u,v)\in F$ there is a $g\in\mathcal G$ such that $u=\int_a^b g(x)dx$ and $v=\int_a^b xg(x)dx$, and *vice versa.* (Represent $g$ as a weighted combination of $g_u$, namely $g(x) = \int_a^b g_{b-u}(x)\, dg(u)$.)
It is easy to see that $F=\{(u,v): u\ge 0,\,(a+b)u/2 \le v \le b u\}$.

We are asked for a $C\in(0,1)$ such that if $(u,v)\in F$, with $v>b^2$, it is guaranteed that $v-au > Cb^2.$  Any $C\in(0, (b-a)/(a+b)$ will do.
One checks that the points in $F$ with $v\ge b^2$ lie in an unbounded  convex polytope  $F^*$, bounded above by the lines $v=bu$ and below by the lines $v=b^2$ and $v=(a+b)u/2.$  There are 2 extreme points, $E_1 = (b,b^2)$ where the lines $v=bu$ and $v=b^2$ intersect, and $E_2=(2b^2/(a+b),b^2)$ where the lines $v=b^2$ and $v=(a+b)u/2$ intersect.  What is required of $C$ is that the minimum of the linear form $v-au$ on $F^*$ is at least $C$.  This happens with the indicated $C$, with the minimum being attained at $E_2.$